# SyntaxError: invalid syntax "if stack [-1].pop () != brackets [stack [-2].pop ()]:"

Tags: python, syntax-error

Does anyone know why I'm getting this syntax error?

```
n = len (stack [-1])
            
for i in range (n -1):
    stack [-1].append (stack [-2].pop ()
                       
if stack [-1].pop () != brackets [stack [-2].pop ()]:
    balance = False
    
elif stack == [[], []]:
    balance = True

if stack [-1] == [] and stack [-2] == []:
    stack.pop()
```

> if stack [-1].pop () != brackets [stack [-2].pop ()]:
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please provide the full reproducible code for the full method.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `)` in the end of line 4:

```py
stack [-1].append (stack [-2].pop ()
```

Should be:

```py
stack [-1].append (stack [-2].pop ())
```